# hibernate cascading delete with multiple levels

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-cascade

sadly I couldn't find a solution for my current problem. (Please post a link if i missed something)

I have a multiple layer entity structure as following

```java
class Parent {

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "parent",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Set<ChildA> setOfChildA = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
    private Set<ChildB> setOfChildB = new HashSet<>();
}

class ChildB {
    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "childb", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
    private Set<grandchild> grandchild = new HashSet<>();
}
```

When I'm adding `Parent.setOfChildA` and adding `ChildB.grandchild` and only saving the Parent entity everything works fine.

But when I'm deleting `Parent.setOfChildA` and deleting some of `ChildB.grandchild` I'm getting the following Exception

```
.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 2; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 2; expected: 1]
```

Hibernate logs the following sql statements

```sql
delete 
        from
            tbl_childa
        where
            childa_linkparentid=? 
            and childa_linkotherentityid=?
delete 
        from
            tbl_grandchild
        where
            grandchild_id=? 
            and grandchild_version=?
```

Does anyone have a clue why adding is working but deleting throwing an exception?

Do you need more information on the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... the error was caused by corrupt data...